Visual Studio Code can't run MAUI projects
I'm trying to deploy a NET8 MAUI application from Visual Studio 2022 from my Windows laptop but I get always the error

error MT1045: Failed to execute 'devicectl': 'devicectl -j /var/folders/dm/bwmxpbzn6bvdsyy73c_b453w0000gn/T/tmpBkAavG.tmp device install app --device "Enrico???s iPhone" /Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3e0740198296a93338bb3c829bc9cf7/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone15.2-17.3.1/LanguageInUse.app' returned the exit code 1

So, I thought to install Visual Studio Code on my iMac and deploy the application from it. I installed all the recommended packages in VSCode

When I load the MAUI project, I get those errors

NET MAUI SDK: not found. Please check the .NET MAUI output window for more info.


Failed to restore solution. Source C# Dev Kit


If I try to run the project, there is no profile for MAUI (also if I search)

How can I fix those issues?

You are better off running VS for mac, that is what i am doing for the time being

VS alias Visual Studio is not supported for longer...

Yeah but until then you would be better off not using VS code it has a gazillion bugs

If you want to create a MAUI project using VS Code, after opening VS Code, in the Welcome page， click Get Started with .NET MAUI in Walkthroughs. Complete the three steps:

Connect account to C# Dev Kit
Set up your .NET environment (Install .NET SDK)
Set up your .NET MAUI environment (enter donet workaround install maui in the terminal).

Then click Create .NET Project in EXPLOREER and select .NET MAUI APP.

Thank you. I have done all of them but it is not working.

After completing the steps in the answer, reopen a new VS Code, click Explorer, click the Create .NET Project button, is there .NET MAUI APP option in the pop-up list? In addition, regarding your problem of not being able to deploy the app to the iPhone by Windows VS, you can refer toDeploy to device
